# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, selenium, null, selenium-webdriver, nullreferenceexception

When I run this program in NUnit I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Though this is not the original program I get a similar error there too. Any help appreciated. Exception occurs at

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace Class_and_object
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class Class1
  {
     IWebDriver driver = null;
     [Test]
     public void test1()
     {
        class2 obj = new class2();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        obj.method();
     }
   }
  public class class2
  {
    IWebDriver driver = null;
    public void method()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot a  `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` in class2 method()?

Comment: In future, when you write a question involving an exception, please show us *where* the exception occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object in a class It needs to be instantiate before you can use it. Arguably one of the best places to do this is in you constructor.

like this:

```
public class class2
{
   IWebDriver driver = null;


   public class2(IWebDriver driver)
   {
      this.driver = driver;
   }
   public void method()
   {
     driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
   }
}
```

and then your other class would look like this

```
public void test1()
 {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    class2 obj = new class2(driver);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    obj.method();
 }
```

Comment: You can't make a new instance of an interface... you need to instantiate a class that implements the interface.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I dont think the answerer was providing actual code, but guiding OP what to do. None knows what the concrete type is..

Comment: You're right, I realized IWebDriver is an interface. Fixed it

Comment: Supposedly it's a FirefoxDriver.

Comment: @reza Thanks alot. My program works now. I wanted to know how to call methods by creating an object. I know it dint work because i have set it as null but i didnt know an alternative way to write it. This is what I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your code:

```
public class class2
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;
    public void method()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    }
}
```

Of course you're getting a `NullReferenceException` - `driver` is always `null`.

It's not clear what you expected to happen here - but perhaps you meant to pass the `FirefoxDriver` you instantiate in `test1` into `method` via a parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I get a NullReferenceException. So what should be written instead of Iwebdriver driver = null;

Comment: @jessica: Well we don't know which object you want to call the method on. The same one that you instantiated in `test1`, or a different one? If you're fairly new to C# (which sounds like it's the case, if you were surprised by getting an exception here) I would strongly suggest that automating web tests isn't a great starting point - I suggest learning the core of the language more first.

Comment: You should instantiate your driver object before calling its navigate method.

Comment: I wanted to call it on test1 only. Yes you are right. Im a beginner trying to learn C#. So not sure how to correct the errors. Thanks for the suggestion and your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the `driver` in your `Class1`, so when it tries to navigate on `class2`'s `method` it fails, as `class2`'s `driver` is `null`. You need to assign it a value before calling any methods on it.

I don't know why you **wouldn't** expect it to fail with a `NullReferenceException`.

What you probably meant to write was:

```
  public class class2
  {
    public void method(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    }
  }
```

and where you call the method in `Class1`:

```
    obj.method(driver);
```

Comment: Yes I get a NullReferenceException. So what should be written instead of Iwebdriver driver = null;

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the reference of `driver` in `Class1` to `Class2` and assign it to the `driver` in there. When you pass by reference, you pass the memory address so the `driver` in `Class2` becomes the same `driver` in `Class1` because they both point to the same address in computer memory.

To pass the driver by reference in `Class1` you need below;

```
obj.method(driver);
```

You need to modify `Class2` so it can receive an `IWebDriver` in `method()`.