# Unable to locate the web element for Kendo grid cell

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, kendo-grid

I am automating a web application has Kendo UI using C# selenium. When I try to add a record in a cell of kendo grid, the element is having null value and getting the error as 'Object reference not set to an instance'. The Html code for the selected cell is 
"". Thank you.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: <td data-field="Code" class="k-state-border-down" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="billofgrid_tt_active"></td>

Comment: Provide your code on exactly which line you have exceptions or errors, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862977/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object